# Cómo convertir un collection_select en un search selection con Semantic-UI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

En la mayoria de formularios existen las listas de selección donde tenemos la opción de seleccionar una o varias opciones dependiendo de las relaciones que hallamos definido en nuestro modelo. En mi caso tengo un collection_select en mi app rails a la que quiero incorporarles opciones de busqueda, igual que el chosen de jquery pero implementando la clase Search Selection de semantic-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con algo de javascript

```
$('#id_del_campo').addClass("ui fluid search selection dropdown")
  .dropdown()
;
```

El id del campo es generado automáticamente al renderizar el formulario.